# Insufficient privileges to write to schema extensions

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've registered a schema extension for users.

I'd like to use it to store data about users after they login to an app, however I cant figure out the permissions. On my (admin) account I'm able to, no problem but on normal user accounts I receive:

```
"error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "2ee94ed5-f351-4992-8db0-2e3b420aa581",
        "date": "2017-10-04T09:37:49"
    }
}
```

The reason I'm using a schema extension instead of an open extensions (which does work), is that I need to be able to filter users by their extension. I cant seem to do this with an open extension.

The PATCH request is as follows:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

```js
{
    "extkh2zr49b_notifications":{
        "badgeCount":"0",
        "pushToken":"test",
    }   
}
```

And my delegated permissions for the app are:

`profile`, `openid`, `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, `User.ReadWrite.All`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've concluded its impossible for normal users to edit their schema extensions. I tried granting every available permission.

I ended up using an open extension instead. I was able to return all of members of a group as well as their extensions. This was enough for me (far better than checking every user in the organisation for an extension...)

The query is below:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[id]/members/$/microsoft.graph.user?$expand=extensions&$select=id

I couldn't find this in any of Microsoft's official documentation so hopefully it continues to work!

Answer (score 1):

Before a normal user can leverage certain scopes, you first need to provide [Admin Consent](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service#3-get-administrator-consent) for those scopes. In your case the scopes `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and `User.ReadWrite.All` require consent.

You might find this article helpful: [v2 Endpoint and Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/).

Comment: I'm using the V1 endpoint and have granted permission through the Azure AD portal. I tried granting using https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent but I'm still receiving the same error?